# Laravel 5.2 $this->request is null

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-5, httprequest

I have following code where I try to make a post call through routes in laravel :

routes.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
Route::post(config('api.basepath') . 'users/parent', array(
    'uses' => 'UserAccountController@createParent'
));
```

The method createParent() is as follows in the UserAccount Controller =>

UserAccountController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Mail;
use Lang;
use Validator;
use Hash;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Log;

class UserAccountController extends Controller
{

    public function createParent()
    {
        Log::info($this->request);
        $this->verify($this->request, 'validations.user.create');
        ......
        ......
    }
}
```

This is the Output :

```
[2016-11-11 13:43:06] local.INFO: null 

#0 /home/test/myproject/web/app/Http/Controllers/UserAccountController.php(268): App\Http\Controllers\Controller->verify(NULL, 'validations.use...')
#1 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\UserAccountController->createParent()
#2 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(80): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('createParent', Array)
#4 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\UserAccountController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'createParent')
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#10 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\UserAccountController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'createParent')
#11 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'createParent')
#12 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#32 /home/test/myproject/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /home/test/myproject/web/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 {main}
```

Please Help. I am stuck at this for hours now.

Comment: So... where did you define the property `$request`?  Why do you expect it to exist or be filled?

Comment: Pass the request to your controller method.

Comment: Inside your `createParent()` method, try to dump the request data using Laravel helper function like so: `dd(request()->all());`. Let us know what do you get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work.
It was a code issue.

EDIT

Actually it was having an issue because in my class, I used another class, and initialised its object. But this class constructor in turn expected further class initialisation that it included in its class. SO I had to initialise those sub-dependent classes to and then initialise the class object.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be as:

```
public function createParent(Request $request)
{
    Log::info($request);
    $this->verify($request, 'validations.user.create');
    ......
    ......
}
```

And make sure to import the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class at top of your controller as:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: ...or inject the Request and set the `$request`-property through the (parent) constructor.

Comment: I already have this  in my App\Http\Controllers\Controller.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs;

    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You never passed request class object in your method createParent().

Try this

```
public function createParent(Request $request) 
{
    $inputs = $request->all(); 
}
```

Comment: Please read the existing answers before repeating the same thing for the fourth time, one hour after OP has stated that this is not the problem...